# Tokenize Timestamp with jFlex and handle ISO format

Tags: java, tokenize, jflex

I am trying to solve an date tokenization issue with various date format, and one of them maybe in ISO8601 format, which using a 'T' as a delimiter. And I want to be able to know character 'T' is a timestamp when it has a digit preceding and following it.

For instance, if I have an array

```
String[] timestamp = {"Time: 12/45/60", "2015-07-13T05:30:59"}
```

I want a splitted result of

```
(Time) (:) (12) (/) (45) (/) (60) 
(2015) (-) (07) (-) (13) (T) (05) (:) (30) (:) (59)
```

I am using jFlex to make the tokenizer, and I wrote my .flex file as such:

```
    %%
    %class Lexer
    SpecialT = (\dT\d)
    Parameter = [:jletterdigit:]+
    Delimiter = [^A-Za-z0-9]|{SpecialT}
    %%
    [:digit:]+ {return new Datetoken(yytext(), "Int");}
    {Delimiter} {return new Datetoken(yytext(), "Delimiter");}
    {Parameter} {return new Datetoken(yytext(), "Text");}
```

However, this tokenizer only parse out symbols, but not 'T'. Anyone has some suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, or rather it works as the grammar describes things.

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
7-29T08:42
[Int] 7
[Delimiter] -
[Text] 29T08
[Delimiter] :
[Int] 42
[Delimiter]
```

Indeed, after the scanner matches the `-` delimiter

- it gets `2`, which matches [:digit:]+, and {Parameter}
- it gets `9`, which matches [:digit:]+, and {Parameter}
- it gets `T`, which doesn't match [:digit:]+ but still matches {Parameter}
- then `0` and `8` keep matching {Parameter}
- `:` doesn't match {Parameter}; and the token `{Parameter} 29T08` is returned.

Note that {SpecialT} is recognized if you enter only that:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
5T6
[Delimiter] 5T6
```

Your first problem is that SpecialT is capturing too much.

Your second problem is that {Parameter} matches virtually everything.

I suggest you define an ISO date more accurately:

```
// HH:MM or HH:MM:ss
IsoTime = {Dig2} {Delimiter} {Dig2} ({Delimiter} {Dig2})?

// yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-mm-ddT<isotime>
IsoDate =  {Dig4} ({Delimiter} {Dig2}){2} (T {IsoTime})?
```

This will create a nice token with the full 2015-07-29T16:42.